# PyQt4: combine textChanged and editingFinished for QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots, qlineedit

Is there a way to combine `textChanged` and `editingFinished` for `QLineEdit`? The problem is that `editingFinished` is emitted even if I only move the cursor away from `QLineEdit` without any changes. Whereas I want to emit a signal only when any changes were performed after I finished editing.

I can imagine only to store somewhere the current text, compare the entered text with it and do something only if it differs. But I wonder if there is any solution purely based on signals handling.

**EDIT:** At the end I had to store the current text and compare with the new text and not follow the proposed solution. I realized that in my application "1.2345" and "1.23" would be the same text but nevertheless I have to update some other values in this case and so on. I really appreciate detailed answer and comments by @Avaris and @ekhumoro, and will accept it since it seems to solve originally posted problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit**

For capturing manual edits:

```
class MyLineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    textModified = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str) # (before, after)

    def __init__(self, contents='', parent=None):
        super(MyLineEdit, self).__init__(contents, parent)
        self.returnPressed.connect(self.checkText)
        self._before = contents

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        if event.reason() != QtCore.Qt.PopupFocusReason:
            self._before = self.text()
        super(MyLineEdit, self).focusInEvent(event)

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        if event.reason() != QtCore.Qt.PopupFocusReason:
            self.checkText()
        super(MyLineEdit, self).focusOutEvent(event)

    def checkText(self):
        if self._before != self.text():
            self._before = self.text()
            self.textModified.emit(self._before, self.text())
```

**Edit 2**

For capturing all edits (programmatic and manual):

```
class MyLineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    textModified = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str) # (before, after)

    def __init__(self, contents='', parent=None):
        super(MyLineEdit, self).__init__(contents, parent)
        self.editingFinished.connect(self.checkText)
        self.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.checkText())
        self.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.checkText(True))
        self._before = contents

    def checkText(self, _return=False):
        if (not self.hasFocus() or _return) and self._before != self.text():
            self._before = self.text()
            self.textModified.emit(self._before, self.text())
```

**Edit 3**

For capturing only text changes by the user:

```
class MyLineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    textModified = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str) # (before, after)

    def __init__(self, contents='', parent=None):
        super(MyLineEdit, self).__init__(contents, parent)
        self.editingFinished.connect(self.__handleEditingFinished)
        self.textChanged.connect(self.__handleTextChanged)
        self._before = contents

    def __handleTextChanged(self, text):
        if not self.hasFocus():
            self._before = text

    def __handleEditingFinished(self):
        before, after = self._before, self.text()
        if before != after:
            self._before = after
            self.textModified.emit(before, after)
```

Comment: Your solution seems incomplete. For example, the signal will fire if the line-edit's context menu is opened (so maybe you need to check the `event.reason()`). Also, the signal *won't* fire if return/enter is pressed - so some keyboard handling is needed.

Comment: @ekhumoro: You are right about those issues. Updated my answer.

Comment: Not bad - but what if e.g. `setText()` or `clear()` is called between edits?

Comment: @ekhumoro: Argh, this is going to turn into a new `QLineEdit` implementation :). Then comes `del`, `backspace`, `insert`, etc... Hmm I think I have a solution for all.

Comment: I think the `_before` attribute should be set before any signals are emitted, as the text could be modified by a handler. But even so: is the OP's spec matched? The signal should be emitted *"only when any changes were performed after I finished editing"*. Whereas your current solution may also emit `textModified` after programmatic text changes.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Oh, I took your comment about `setText` as 'it won't fire with `setText`'. So you meant just updating `_before`. OK, that depends on what 'editing' means. I thought any means of editing (programmatic/manual) is 'editing', and changed the subclass accordingly. Otherwise `focus*Event` method works there. I'll put that back up.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Also good point about setting `_before` before the emit. Only problem with the `focus*Event` solution I see is if someone alters the text while editing, `_before` would be off (e.g. connecting `returnPressed` to `clear`). For that, I have no solution besides re-writing many methods that alter the text programmatically. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: +1 For your efforts :) As these comments are getting rather long, I took the liberty of adding an alternative example to your answer to show exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: @ekhumoro: :) That's good too. That still behaves weirdly with `returnPressed` connected to `clear`, but to be fair, I'm not sure how it's supposed to behave for that :).

Comment: Perhaps this all goes to show why Qt doesn't try to implement this behaviour. Having looked again at my alternative, I'm not sure I really like it now! Maybe there just isn't a good, general solution to this problem...

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to detect whether *any* changes have been made (as opposed to whether the text is different from how it started), you can use the [`modified`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qlineedit.html#modified-prop) property of the `QLineEdit` with the [`editingFinished`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) signal:

```
    self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
    self.edit.editingFinished.connect(self.handleEditingFinished)
    ...

def handleEditingFinished(self):
    if self.edit.isModified():
        # do interesting stuff ...
        print 'Editing Finished'
    self.edit.setModified(False)
```

Comment: Note that `modified` will stay toggled even if you revert it back to the original value before finishing the edit.